# Auto format date with Zend_Form_Element_DateTextBox

Tags: zend-form, dojo

guys, this is a short to the point question. Is it possible to auto add the "slashes" on a Zend_Form_Element_DateTextBox while the user is typing? For example, et say my format is dd/mm/yyyy . So the user would start typing `12` and the system would automatically add the `/`after it. So when typing a date you wouldn't have to add them, but simply, for example, typing `12052009` would correctly format it to `12/05/2009`

Answer (score 0):

No, its not. And i think this **would not** be a good thing to add to the dojo functionality.

What if someone wants to type 1/1/2009:

Then you automatically would get 11/20/09. You would have to have to ask the user to use zeros (01/01/2009) in some way ! Would be frustrating !